New H1B visa amendment request
My H1B was approved recently by USCIS with the LCA role of Senior Associate. I've since been promoted to Manager and will file an amendment for the designation change to update my role. Will this delay my visa stamping process, and how long does the amendment process usually take?

I do not think the question is about travels. expatriate SE may be more relevant (see links in top right icon). Do it matter the tittle? Considering that only 1 in 10 will be approved (there is a cap) your expertise, not the tittle, matter

There's definitely a need to notify if the title changes, and the LCA is based on that.
